# Regular Expression Error: 'bad escape \c at position 3' - How to Resolve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

My pattern is not compiling in regex and giving bad escape error, is there any way to resolve

```
import re 
text = "n\\c" 
pattern = rf"\\b{text.lower()}\\b" 
re.search(pattern, "hello", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

> Python - 3.8,
> re version - 2.2.1

I want to use text in pattern to find it in my search string for example "hello".
Text in a pattern will vary

Example 1

> text = "a sleep", sentence= "A lazy fox jump over a sleeping dog",
> Output: None

Example 2

> text = "a sleeping", sentence= "A lazy fox jump over a sleeping dog"
> Output : "a sleeping

Comment: What should the `\\c` in `text` mean?

Comment: I have a list of strings which can contain such kind of text which doesn't make any sense and I want to handle such cases using regex, but my pattern is not compiling that's problem for the given text, is there any way to handle ?

Comment: `pattern = rf"\b{re.escape(text.lower())}\b"` Note you don't need to escape \ in a raw string

Comment: Please give some examples of input and the expected output.

Comment: Oh, guess we have to run your code.. Normally `\c` is an escape sequence that denotes a _control character. Without a follow character its an unknown sequence.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're using an f-string to construct the pattern, but you're also using the \b word boundary escape sequence and doubling the backslashes. However, the \b and double backslashes are not necessary in this case.

So, to fix this issue, you can modify the code as follows:

```
import re
text = r"n\\c"
pattern = re.escape(text.lower())
print(pattern)
match = re.search(pattern, "hello", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(match)
```

Comment: In case of "hello" it works but if I have a sentence  and I don't want it to partially match, This will fail

Comment: This is not related to the problem in the question. The O.P. is issuing a manual escape to include the \\ character in a string, but upon e bedding the first string on the second the escape is already consumed. Easily fixeable by using raw strings.

Comment: Actually, it is a bit related in that you are correctly using re.escape - but that should be the main point of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```py
text = "a sleep"
sentence= "A lazy fox jump over a sleeping dog"
m = re.search(rf'(?i)\b{re.escape(text)}\b', sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Older*** Python regex restricts escape sequences it does not support.
It throws errors.
Most engines just strip the escape.

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = "\c"
>>> re.search(pat, "hello")
re.error: bad escape \c at position 0
```

`\cX` is a *Control Character* construct that requires the *X* and is not
supported by a lot of engines. Python being one ?